# How to style a select placeholder in Angular 8?

Tags: html, css, angular

There are many old answers out there about defining a placeholder on an HTML select, though only a few work with Angular. And with Angular 8, the ONLY way I've been able to get a placeholder is with the following:

```
<select [(ngModel)]='expiryMonth' name='expiryMonth'> 
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" hidden selected>Select Month</option>                                      
    <option *ngFor="let item of expiryMonths" [value]="item.number" [selected]="item.number == expiryMonth">{{item.number}} - {{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

But I cannot find any CSS to style this placeholder with a different color or opacity to suggest a placeholder. Anyone?

Comment: Are you using angular material? If not I don't think this question is related to angular as the core framework shouldn't be styling ```select``` which is a native HTML element

Comment: I'm trying to switch from ng-select to HMTL <select> for accessibility reasons. Running into a mountain of styling issues, some of which probably can't be overcome.

Comment: Gotcha. I was asking because angular material obviously overrides the style and it is a pain to change it unless you create your own theme. What is wrong with ```option{
  color: black;
}

select{
  color: red;
}``` ? If you don't want to style regular selected values, you can always set a ```ngClass``` and only style the value if an option isn't selected